# What applications can I disable on my Samsung Galaxy S4?

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I have just bought a Samsung Galaxy S4 and discovered that it comes with a large number of programs that I know I will never use (Amazon MP3, all Samsung Apps, TripAdvisor etc.). I have found that they can be disabled by going to `Settings > More > Application Manager`, selecting a specific application and choosing `Disable`. The problem is that I don't know which applications can be safely disabled.

Can someone provide a definitive list of all the applications installed on a new Galaxy S4 along with whether they are required or not?

Comment: I can provide the list and maybe turn this into a wiki if anyone is interested?

Comment: Anything with a "Disable" button should be safe to disable. Crucial system apps won't be listed in the app manager or, if they are, won't allow you to disable them. You'll never get a "definitive" list of the apps you can shut off. At best, you might be able to get a good list of the apps you should leave alone.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [DjeMBeY's pre-rooted S4 thread in XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2250824). The author has debloated (i.e. removed unecessary apps) the stock S4 ROM. There is a download link that contains all the APKs that he has removed; search for `Removed Apps`. It is safe to assume that these apps are safe to be deleted.

Better yet, why don't you just flash his custom ROM? That seems easier. :)